# Auto Login Facebook User After Accepting Permissions

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to login users automatically into my site who have already allowed our facebook app, initially I was going to use :

```
  var cb = function(response) {   
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
       FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        $.post( url, { 'op':'facebook','name':response['name'],'id':response['id'],'email':response['email']},
           function( data ) {
                parent.location.reload();

           });
      });
    } else {
      alert('You are not logged in');
    }
  };
  FB.login(cb, { scope: 'publish_actions,publish_stream,read_stream,email' });
```

Although using that it opens a facebook popup, blocked by many popup blockers and browsers when done in an automatic manner like this and will also display for users who have no allowed our app.

I want it to be done descretely but I'm not sure how :S

If anyone could show me how to log them in using javascript that would be great :)

Answer (score 1):

Prompting a user to login should be hinged off of a user generated event, like clicking on an element. Most browsers will block attempts to automatically open new windows unless there is enough confidence that the user has requested the action.

If you want to automatically detect a visitor's login status when they load your page, you should hook onto the various auth events exposed by the Javascript SDK ("auth.authResponseChange", "auth.login", etc), or manually request the visitor's status using the "FB.getLoginStatus" method. You can read more about these events at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Comment: I had a look at that and it's pretty similar to what I have, I still havn't been able to silently login the user using those tutorials :(

Comment: One thing to look out for is, if you're only using the Javascript SDK to detect a logged in user, set the "status" parameter for the "[FB.init](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/)" method to true. This will prompt Facebook to fetch the user's logged in status on page load. You can also pass a boolean flag as a second parameter to FB.getLoginStatus which will force Facebook to fetch the user's login status. Your updated code would be `FB.getLoginStatus(cb, true);`

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working! Read the facebook tutorial again and this is what I came up with

```
window.onload=function(){
var url = "http://mysite.com/";
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
       FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        $.post( url, { 'op':'facebook','name':response['name'],'id':response['id'],'email':response['email']},
           function( data ) {
                parent.location.reload();

           });
        });
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: this still isn't very secure, just keep in mind that someone could send a $.post() with anyone's fbID / Name from the console. I pass the authToken to my application then have the server get "/me"